# What is the meaning of difficult sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0379786/synopsis)

> the Alliance follows, mentioning the war for system-wide control --
>   the War of Independence, as it's known to the losing opposition, the
>   Browncoats.

Quite didn't understand this statement.

Comment: whole sentence is confusing, I hope someone will give the answer to it. thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need further context,

> The pre-title teaser provides backstory for those unfamiliar with the Firefly TV series. The events in the teaser occur prior to the first episode of the TV series: The Universal logo changes to show ships leaving 25th Century Earth as a teacher's voice-over describes the exodus from "Earth that was" and the terraforming and colonization of planets in the new 'verse.'
>
> An introduction to the system government known as the Alliance follows, mentioning the war for system-wide control -- the War of Independence, as it's known to the losing opposition, the Browncoats.

The word *follows* refers to "the introduction": it comes *after* the "pre-title teaser". So, the introductions follows (comes after) the pre-title teaser. Next, this introduction is about

> the system government known as the "Alliance".

The em dash (--, —) serves to insert more information into the sentence.

> the War of Independence, as it's known to the losing opposition, the Browncoats.

The "war for system-wide control" is known as the *War of Independence* to the Browncoats. The Browncoats are the losing opposition.